# Requesting html from a remote document via jQuery .load() method

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load html content from another page via .load(). For example:

```
$('#myDiv').load('/myPage.aspx .anotherDiv *');
```

When I retrieve the content from .anotherDiv it renders the html incorrectly. For example,

```
<p><strong>text</strong></p>
```

renders like this

```
<p></p>
<strong>text</strong>
```

Some how the "p" element is getting unwrapped then prepends to its original "strong" child element.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that the first arg of `.load` is URL which seems to be incorrect in your post. Just a comment.

Comment: @Vega He's using a valid overload which allows the implementer to specify a selector on the destination response.

Comment: @NathanTaylor Aaww I see, it is there in the documentation.. first time seeing such syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `*` from your call to load().

```
$('#myDiv').load('/myPage.aspx .anotherDiv');
```

Let us know what happens.

Comment: That worked! It includes the .anotherDiv. Is there a way to exclude it without using .unwrap()? I only want the innerHTML of .anotherDiv.